# Create element with custom HTML attributes in Jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to generate an anchor with jQuery, using some custom HTML5 attributes to get something like this.

```
$('<a/>', {href : "#local_anchor",text: "DUMMY_TOKEN", onClick:"remote_function('token')"}).attr("data-toggle", "modal")
```

If i use this code it works just fine.

```
$('<a/>', {
   href : "#local_anchor",
   text: "DUMMY_TOKEN",
   onClick:"remote_function('token')"
}).attr("data-toggle", "modal")
```

But i would like to pass data-toggle as an parameter along the first href, text, etc. 
When i try to do that i get an Syntax Error.

I also tried to use .data() but i couldn't set the value in the markup, only in DOM.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just quote `data-toggle` and it will work:

```
$("<a/>", {
    href: "#local_anchor",
    text: "DUMMY_TOKEN",
    onClick: "remote_function('token')",
    "data-toggle": "modal"
});
```